# Repeating sequence of operations without for loop

Tags: r

I have a simulation in R that involves executing several lines of code. 
I would like to replicate this process 1000 times.

Is there any way to do this withouth a for-loop?

I know there is replicate() but that can only replicate 1 process at a time.

Here's an example:

```
for (r in 1:reps){

first<-sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(c(1,2),100,prob=c(0.45,0.55),replace=T))

second<-sapply(2:100, function(i) length(which(apply(sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(easy[x,],i)),2,max)==2)) )

third[r,]<-second
}
```

Can this be done withouth a for loop?

Comment: You could in theory throw this into a function and use  `sapply`  again, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is `easy` defined as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `replicate` is useful for you (it's really just a wrapper of `sapply`, but makes your code more readable). I've also made the inside of your loop slightly more readable:

```
set.seed(123)
for (r in 1:reps){  
  #  first <- matrix(sample(c(1,2),100*100,prob=c(0.45,0.55),replace=T), nrow=100)
  second <- sapply(2:100, function(i) length(which(apply(sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(easy[x,],i)),2,max)==2)) )
  third[r,]<-second
}   
set.seed(123)
third.2 <- t(replicate(reps, sapply(2:100, function(i) 
  sum(apply(easy[1:100, ], 1, function(x) max(sample(x, i))==2)))))
all.equal(third, third.2)
```

By the way, even tough you didn't ask for this, here is a faster way to calculate `first`, which does not need `sapply`at all.

```
set.seed(123)
first <- sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(c(1,2),100,prob=c(0.45,0.55),replace=T))
set.seed(123)
first.2 <- matrix(sample(c(1,2), 100*100, prob=c(0.45,0.55), replace=T), nrow=100)
all.equal(first, first.2)
```

Comment: How can you run this without defining `reps` and `easy`?

Comment: I cannot, but I think making a reproducible example should be part of the question, not the answer (altough of course if the question has a reproducible example, the answer should follow-up on it).

Comment: Just FYI, I used `reps <- 10` and `easy <- matrix(sample(1:5, (100*100), replace=TRUE), nrow=100)`

Comment: Agreed.  Your `set.seed()` calls threw me off. :)

Comment: Just figured, if the OP wants to compare my output with his original, it would only make sense with proper seed. But agreed, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: I admire you for attempting to make sense of `sapply>length>which>apply>sapply>sample`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, something like this would enable you to avoid the loop.

```
foo = function (dummy) {
first<-sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(c(1,2),100,prob=c(0.45,0.55),replace=T))

second<-sapply(2:100, function(i) length(which(apply(sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(easy[x,],i)),2,max)==2)) )

third[r,]<-second
}

sapply(1:reps, foo)
```

Comment: this would be great, but the third line won't work because its using the reps as an index